# C++ map iterator issue

Tags: c++, gcc, dictionary, iterator

I have a weird error in the following code :

```
float Student::getAverageMark() const throw (NoMarkException)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(map<string, float>::iterator iter = marks.begin(); iter != marks.end(); ++iter) {
        sum += iter->second;
        count++;
    }
    return sum/count;
}
```

As you can see, it's nothing out of the ordinary, it's a simple code that calculates the average marks in a map. I tested this in an online compiler and it worked, but when I try to compile it on my machine (I'm using CodeBlocks with the GNU GCC Compiler) I get this error:

> error: conversion from 'std::map, float>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, float> >}' to non-scalar type 'std::map, float>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator, float> >}' requested|

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a const function that is trying to iterate what I assume is a member variable (marks).
Make sure you use a const iterator:

```
for(map<string, float>::const_iterator iter = marks.begin();
```

Comment: Would have been my answer too. You may have a look at this: http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html

Comment: +1 While you're at it, if using C++11, use `marks.cbegin()` and `marks.cend()`

Comment: Thanks, I'm still very new to C++, and couldn't figure this one out. The error messages don't help much either.

Comment: @VSebi: They're a little cryptic when you haven't seen them before, but once you have a trained eye, this one is a dead giveaway for (indirectly or directly) attempting to use the wrong iterator type. Once you see the word `const_iterator` then the first thing you do is check the type of the container and whether you're in a `const` context. Then it all falls into place in seconds. :) Comes with practice.

Comment: @Lightness Or `std::accumulate`, C++11 or not (although having lambdas does make using an algorithm a lot more palatable in this case)\

Answer (score 2):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956205/241631) shows how to fix the error, but here's another way to calculate the average using [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). Using this method, you don't need to worry about iterator types and such, and the loop can be eliminated as well.

```
float Student::getAverageMark() const throw (NoMarkException)
{
    if(marks.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return std::accumulate(marks.begin(), marks.end(), 0.0f,
                           [](float acc, decltype(marks)::value_type const& elem) {
                              return acc + elem.second;
                           }) / marks.size();
}
```

Also, [exception specifications](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) have been deprecated.